# Is there a way to include compression inside a stored procedure

Tags: teradata

I load multiple tables from inside a stored procedure and was wondering if I would be able to compress the tables when I load. I am not sure how to enable BLC compression from inside a procedure like how we do for a session.

```
SET QUERY_BAND = 'BLOCKCOMPRESSION=YES;' FOR SESSION;
```

Any suggestions in how compress while loading?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use `FOR SESSION`, but `FOR TRANSACTION` like `BEGIN REQUEST; SET QUERY_BAND = 'BLOCKCOMPRESSION=YES;' FOR TRANSACTION; do what you need; END REQUEST;`

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! That's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: This isn't working when I tried. Here is how I am using it.Am I missing anything REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
SET QUERY_BAND = 'BLOCKCOMPRESSION=YES;' FOR TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE A AS B WITH DATA AND STATS;

END;

Comment: You have to add the `BEGIN\END REQUEST;` to submit both the SET and the CREATE as a single request/transaction.